# I can't solve issue "axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0"

Tags: python, numpy, indexoutofboundsexception, odeint, index-error

I'm trying to model the motion of a spring pendulum and this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Specify initial conditions
init = array([pi/18, 0]) # initial values

def deriv(z, t):
    x,y=z
    dy=np.diff(y,1)
    dy2=np.diff(y,2)
    dx=np.diff(x,1)
    dx2=np.diff(x,2)
    dt=np.diff(t,1)
    dt2=np.diff(t,1)
    dx2dt2=(4+x)*(dydt)^2-5*x+9.81*cos(y)
    dy2dt2=(-9.81*sin(y)-2*(dxdt)*(dydt))/(l+x)
    return np.array([dx2dt2,dy2dt2])

time = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
y = odeint(deriv,init,time)

plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.plot(time, y)
plt.show()
```

I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cnoxon/Desktop/GRRR.py", line 24, in <module>
    y = odeint(deriv,init,time)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 233, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))
  File "/Users/cnoxon/Desktop/GRRR.py", line 13, in deriv
    dy=np.diff(y,1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1163, in diff
    axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, nd)
numpy.core._internal.AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

I'm a complete beginner to Python so I won't understand most of the terminology, so please bear with me. How do I fix this problem? I'm trying to plot the solutions to the two equations

```
dx2dt2=(4+x)*(dydt)^2-5*x+9.81*cos(y)
dy2dt2=(-9.81*sin(y)-2*(dxdt)*(dydt))/(l+x)
```

but I'm having a lot of trouble. Would someone please explain to me how I should rewrite my code to resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: `x` and `y` are integers, not arrays, so you can't do `np.diff(y,1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens because `x` and `y` are integers, not arrays, so you can't do `np.diff(y,1)`.

But your problem is deeper. Each entry of the `y` array must fully describe your system, this means that every value needed to compute `dx2dt2` and `dy2dt2` must be in this vector. So `y` has to be a list of `[x, y, dxdt, dydt]`. (Adapt `init` to correspond to this)

Then, your `deriv` function just has to give the derivative of such a vector, which is: `[dxdt, dydt, dx2dt2, dy2dt2]`. Your `deriv` function becomes very simple!

```
def deriv(z, t):
    x, y, dxdt, dydt = z

    dx2dt2=(4+x)*(dydt)^2-5*x+9.81*cos(y)
    dy2dt2=(-9.81*sin(y)-2*(dxdt)*(dydt))/(l+x)

    return np.array([dxdt, dydt, dx2dt2, dy2dt2])
```

---

And you have two other little errors: use `**` instead of `^` in python, and I think you changed a `1` into a `l`...

Comment: Is that the correct approach for 2nd order ODEs? I think you might have to rewrite it as a set of 1st order ODEs and then solve that

Comment: I have two other questions: does python recognize that dx2/dt2 is the second derivative of x, and the same for dy2dt2? I'm not sure how to write the second derivative in python, notation-wise, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, when I change the initial parameters sometimes I get a graph of four functions instead of two. Why is this, and how do I change it so that the initial parameters affect only the functions dx2/dt2 and dy2/dt2 (i.e how do I get only the graph of two functions)? Sorry if this is complicated or unclear.

Comment: @tel Indeed, but that's exactly what I did. Rewriting it as a set of 1st order ODEs corresponds to write `dx2/dt2 = f(dx/dt, t)`, `dx/dt = f(x, t)` etc. Here I combine everything into a first order equation with a vector of dimension 4.

@CharlotteNoxon Python doesn't recognize anything. I don't know if there is a convention for that, but your notation is quite clear, that's the most important.

Comment: For your other question, if`y` and `dydt` are equal to 0, they will stay equal to 0. Then if you write `init = array([pi/18, 0, 0, 0])`, `y` and `dydt` are equal to zero, so there will be no movement for these variables, you will only see `x` and `dxdt` on the plot. However, if you write `init = array([pi/18, pi/18, 0, 0])`, the four values will evolve.
If you want to plot only `x` and `y` without their derivatives, just plot `y[:, :2]` (the first 2 values are `x` and `y`).

Comment: So what I'm trying to plot is dx2/dt2 (i.e. x'') and dy2/dt2 (y'') from the ODEs x''=(m+x)*y'-mx+mcos(y) and y''=(msin(y)-2x'y')/(m+x) where m is an arbitrary constant. It seems to be that this is not what I'm graphing...How would I go about graphing the second derivatives? Sorry for the additional questions.

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote the equation of x'' - it should be x'' = (m+x)*(y')^2-mx+mcos(y)